# Undefined method `to_key' for {:store=>false}:Hash when using `sign_in` helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

I defined this code block in my controller spec:

```
describe "DELETE #destroy" do

  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    sign_in @user, store: false
    delete :destroy, id: @user.auth_token
  end

  it { should respond_with 204 }

end
```

When I run the tests, I receive the error `undefined method 'to_key' for {:store=>false}:Hash`.

This is the associated controller method:

```
def destroy
  user = User.find_by(auth_token: params[:id])
  user.generate_authentication_token!
  user.save
  head 204
end
```

The tests are failing as a result of the error.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This method signature is `sign_in(scope, resource)` so you can't pass a hash to it.

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/sign_in_out.rb) here defines a `sign_in(resource_or_scope, *args)` method signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tests you are using not the same helpers like in controllers. You are using [TestHelpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb#L48) and here is quote from [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb#L48):

> sign_in a given resource by storing its keys in the session.
>   This method bypass any warden authentication callback.
>
> Examples:
>
> sign_in :user, @user   # sign_in(scope, resource)
>      sign_in @user  # sign_in(resource)

So, you can't pass hash to this helper.

Comment: The tests passed when I removed the hash. Does this mean the sessions are not stored even when I don't specify the hash?

Comment: @gnerkus Actually as you can see in source it uses `warden.session_serializer.store(resource, scope)` and there is no way to bypass it like in helper which you are using in controllers. But you can monkey-patch this helper if you need to change it behavior.